# How to convert object name to a String?

Tags: java, string, object, comparison

I have Overridden the toString method, so that my objects return their ID (a parameter I have set within my object.

```
@Override
    public String toString(){
        return getId();
}
```

The problem I have is that I'm searching through a list with references to these objects and I want to be able to do certain actions when X object is present.

In order to do this, I need my program to be able to interpret the returned object ID as a string, as I'm doing a comparison (to check whether it's present).

So my question, how do I convert an object reference to a string in order to make a comparison. Or is there a better way I could do this?

Comment: a the moment is not quite clear what you want to do...

Comment: if you have a list of your objects and you need to filter the list based on object property you can use streams : `list.stream().filter(obj -> X.equals(obj.getId())).foreach(System.out::println)`

Comment: What do you mean? Objects do not have names by themselves. Variables have names, and a variable is a reference to an object. From the object there is no way to get the name of a variable that refers to the object. If you think that is what you need, then you most likely have a misconception about variables and objects and there are other and better ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Question isn't very clear but there is no need for overriding the `toString ` for what you are trying to achieve (i think). [Check the HashMap documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) I think this would be solution to what you are trying to do

Comment: are you trying to compare their id number? because you are just returning their id number.. when you call the overriden `toString` method,

Comment: @abcOfJava, yes I'm trying to compare their id number.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please put up a real [mcve]; containing that code where you iterate your list and want to make those checks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare their id number you can create a overloaded method of `Object`

```
String idNumber;
public boolean equals(YourSuperClass yourSuper)
{
    if(idNumber.equals(yourSuper.getId()))
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```